# How can I get index of rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the below.

```
             customers       ...
Date                                             
2006-01-03          98       ...
2006-01-04         120       ...   
2006-01-05         103       ...  
2006-01-06          95       ... 
2006-01-09         103       ...
```

And I want to get the rows with the numbers of customers over 100 and print them.

```
for x in range(len(df)):
    if df['customers'].iloc[x] > 100:
        print(df['customers'].iloc[x])
```

But I don't know how I can print out the dates(index) of the rows that meet the condition. My goal is to print out like this:

```
2006-01-04
120
2006-01-05
103
2006-01-09
103
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`query()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
print(df)
         Date  customers
0  2006-01-03         98
1  2006-01-04        120
2  2006-01-05        103
3  2006-01-06         95
4  2006-01-09        103

df.query('customers > 100')
         Date  customers
1  2006-01-04        120
2  2006-01-05        103
4  2006-01-09        103
```

To get the exact output format you specified, iterate over the `query()` result:

```
for date, customer in df.query('customers > 100').values:
    print(date)
    print(customer)

2006-01-04
120
2006-01-05
103
2006-01-09
103
```

Comment: Date column is the index of this dataframe. Do you happend to know how to get each Date the customers value of the row of which meets the condition?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for.  If `Date` is the index, the `query()` function works the same way.  If you only want the dates that match your condition (which is not what OP desired output shows), then just extract the `index`:  
`df.query('customers > 100').index.values`

Answer (score 1):

df[df['customer'] > 100] will do the job...
Although you can find many similar answer on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Using your loop, you can get the data in your output by using df.index[x]

```
for x in range(len(df)):
    if df['customers'].iloc[x] > 100:
        print(df.index[x])
        print(df['customers'].iloc[x])

2006-01-04
120
2006-01-05
103
2006-01-09
103
```